# Crystal reports for multiple tables

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm working on designing a crystal report.
I need to display two tables on one page. (In other words, two details sections on each page).

Both the tables have independent records of each other.
e.g.
Table 1 columns are:

```
|Item No | Item Name | Date | Qtty Sold | Selling Price |
```

Table 2 columns are:

```
Item No | Item Details | RemainingQtty |
```

Table 1 has 30 rows and table 2 has 5 rows

Can someone help me out how to achieve this?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3):

**Solved**

I suggest a **single query that reports both the data that you want to show in the two tables** (using UNION; both queries must have same number\type of columns); add an **extra column and call it `Table`**, forcing the value to `1` or `2`.

Inside the report

- Create a `GROUP` based on the report (so all records of Table 1 will be displayed on top and records of Table 2 will be desplayed on bottom)
- Create 2 `DETAIL` and 2 `GROUP HEADER` section to display properly data
- Use this suppress rule `{Command.Table}=1` to display the correct `GROUP HEADER` and `DETAIL`

[Here is link to a sample report](http://beativoi.altervista.org/opentech/DoubleTable.rpt)
 http://beativoi.altervista.org/opentech/DoubleTable.rpt

---

SORT the record based on Table value 
and then create two details sections

Comment: +1 Nice concept, never thought of that. But your sample report link seems to be broken.

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona the link : http://beativoi.altervista.org/opentech/DoubleTable.rpt is good, if I copy and paste into the browser it works.. I made many attempts but don't know why it looks broken!